# "No pixel is not drawn to". No...not structure in this sentence. Could you clarify it in a simpler one?

Tags: meaning

"No pixel is not drawn to". No...not structure in this sentence. Could you clarify it in a simpler one?

> Calling clear before drawing anything is mandatory, otherwise the
> contents from previous frames will be present behind anything you
> draw. The only exception is when you cover the entire window with what
> you draw, so that **no pixel is not drawn to**. In this case you can avoid
> calling clear (although it won't have a noticeable impact on
> performance).

Comment: Double negation. No pixel is missed. Every pixel is drawn to.

Comment: The simpler version (which native speakers would almost always use in such contexts) is *...so that **every pixel is** drawn to*. Most people probably wouldn't include that unnecessary final preposition ***to***, though.

Comment: We can use a double negation for the purpose of emphasising something, e.g. I will leave no stone unturned in my efforts to uncover the truth. The focus is on not missing something.

Comment: That is, we are focusing on avoiding neglect, rather than simply upon completion.

Comment: Please cite your source.